# Perforce sync all files with a specific extension to revision #0

Tags: perforce

I would like to be able to sync to revision #0 for all files with a specific extension (so they get deleted).  These files are taking up too much space and I don't use them.

I have tried a few different things with no luck:

```
p4 sync //root/.../*.psd#0
p4 sync //root/...#0/*.psd
p4 sync //root/.../*.psd@0
```

Comment: If possible, **please include actual error messages** as part of questions rather than just saying something like "it didn't work" -- I gave an answer that covers most of the likely scenarios, but it's much easier to zero in on what specifically went wrong if there's a specific error message to go off of.

Comment: The first reports files-up-to-date (didnt remove the file).
The second reports '0/*.psd' revision invalid.
The third reports no file as of that date.
So likely a stupid syntax thing.

Comment: Yes, reporting the error/result would have helped... in this case I just had a pathing mistake in my test causing it to start at a lower folder then expected.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax you want is:

```
p4 sync //....psd#none
```

(`#none` is the idiomatic way to specify "no revision", but `#0` and `@0` should also work.)

The revision specifier *always* goes immediately *after* the file path, never in the middle of it.  Providing a path like `//root/...#0/*.psd` should have gotten you an error like `Invalid revision number '0/*.psd'`.

Note that if your server is case-sensitive (the default if it's hosted on a Unix platform), all parts of a file path are case-sensitive, so you may need to do both `.psd` and `.PSD` to cover all your bases.

The following variations might work, with caveats:

- `p4 sync //.../*.psd#0` -- this works, but is slower due to the double wildcard.  You almost never want to do `.../*` in place of simply `...`.
- `p4 sync //root/.../*.psd#0` -- this should also work, but only in a depot that is literally called `root`.  The "root" of the repository (i.e. the parent "directory" of all depots) is just `//`.  If you ran a command against a `//root/...` path and there is no `root` depot, you should have gotten an error like `//root/... - must refer to client 'yourclient'`, which is the error you get if you try to reference a specific domain (`//something`) that isn't a depot and isn't your current client.